Cannot deal with ast.litral_eval() function in str_to_dict_eedi_df() function
def str_to_dict_eedi_df(df: pd.DataFrame):
    cols = ["correct_option", "gt_distractors", "generated_distractors", "distractors", "construct_info"]
    cols = [col for col in cols if col in df.columns]
    for i, row in df.iterrows():
        for col in cols:
            try:
                df.at[i, col] = ast.literal_eval(row[col])
            except Exception:
                df.at[i, col] = None
    return df

def process_data(data_address):
    data_file = pd.read_csv(data_address)
    data_file = str_to_dict_eedi_df(data_file)
    data = []
    for _, row in data_file.iterrows():
        temp = {}
        input  = "[INST] You are given the following math question along with the correct answer and explanation. Please use the following template to give three alternative incorrect answers to be used as multiple-choice options in a multiple-choice exam. Prior to the incorrect answer, provide feedback to be displayed to the student as an explanation of why that is not the correct answer.\n" +\
        "[Template]\n" +\
        "Distractor1 Feedback:\n" +\
        "Distractor1:\n" +\
        "Distractor2 Feedback:\n" +\
        "Distractor2:\n" +\
        "Distractor3 Feedback:\n" +\
        "Distractor3:\n" +\
        "Question: " + row["question"].strip() + "\nExplanation: " + row["correct_option"]["explanation"].strip() + " \nAnswer: " + row["correct_option"]["option"].strip() + " [/INST]"
        temp["input"] = input
        output = "\nDistractor1 Feedback: " + row["distractors"][0]["explanation"].strip() + "\nDistractor1: " + row["distractors"][0]["option"].strip() 
        output += "\nDistractor2 Feedback: " + row["distractors"][1]["explanation"].strip() + "\nDistractor2: " + row["distractors"][1]["option"].strip()
        output += "\nDistractor3 Feedback: " + row["distractors"][2]["explanation"].strip() + "\nDistractor3: " + row["distractors"][2]["option"].strip()
        temp["output"] = output
        data.append(temp)
    return data


temp_data = process_data("data/eedi_train_80_cleaned_4_18.csv")

While calling str_to_dict_eedi_df()
it convert all entry to none? don't know why my ast.litral_eva() function pass an error.
I there any one kind enough to help me with the code
